Restricting a RAG Chatbot's Responses to a Specific PDF
I've created a chatbot using an OpenAI model and Langchain and instructed it via system messages to only answer questions related to a specific PDF. While it works initially, the chatbot eventually starts responding to unrelated queries. How can I ensure the chatbot remains restricted to answering questions solely based on the content of the designated PDF?

It may be related to the specific system messages that you prompted, along with the memory capabilities of the agent. However, without looking at the code, this is a blind guess. Can you provide some snippets to better understand the issue?
